# could not find function "merge_eurostat_geodata"

Tags: data, merge, maps, ggplot2, maptools

Just a couple of codes with the same error at the time of merge data:

FIRST CODE:

```
library(eurostat)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
fer <- search_eurostat("fertility")
get_eurostat("demo_r_frate2", time_format = "raw", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  %>%
dplyr::mutate(cat = cut_to_classes(values, n=7, decimals = 1)) %>%
merge_eurostat_geodata(data=.,geocolumn="geo",resolution = "20",  output_class = "df", all_regions = FALSE) %>%  
ggplot(data=., aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group)) +
geom_polygon(aes(fill=cat),color="dim grey", size=.1) +
scale_fill_manual(values =  c("#d73027","#fc8d59","#fee08b","#ffffbf","#d9ef8b","#91cf60","#1a9850")) +
# scale_fill_continuous(trans = 'reverse', ) +
guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=T, title = "Total fertility rate (%)")) +
labs(title="Total fertility rate, by NUTS-3 regions, 2014",
subtitle="Average number of live births per woman",
caption="(C) EuroGeographics for the administrative boundaries 
Map produced in R with a help from Eurostat-package  <github.com/ropengov/eurostat/>") +
theme_light() + theme(legend.position=c(.8,.8), text=element_text(family="opensans")) +
coord_map(project="orthographic", xlim=c(-12,44), ylim=c(35,70))
```

> Error in merge_eurostat_geodata(data = ., geocolumn = "geo",
>   resolution = "20",  :  couldn't find function "merge_eurostat_geodata"

SECOND CODE:

```
# Data from Eurostat
current_pop <- get_eurostat("demo_r_pjangrp3", time_format = "raw",   stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
filter(time == 2015, 
     nchar(geo) == 4,
     sex == "T", 
     age == "TOTAL") %>% 
select(-unit) %>% 
rename(current = values,
     time_current = time)
projected_pop <- get_eurostat("proj_15npms", time_format = "raw",  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
filter(time == 2050, 
     nchar(as.character(geo)) == 4,
     sex == "T", 
     age == "TOTAL") %>% 
rename(projected = values,
     time_projected = time)

 left_join(current_pop,projected_pop) %>% 
 mutate(change = projected / current * 100 -100) %>% 
 dplyr::mutate(cat = cut_to_classes(change, manual = TRUE, manual_breaks =  c(-50,-10,0,10,25,130))) %>%
 # dplyr::mutate(cat = cut_to_classes(change)) %>%
 # merge with geodata
 merge_eurostat_geodata(data=.,geocolumn="geo",resolution = "20",  output_class = "df", all_regions = FALSE) %>% 
 # plot map
 ggplot(data=., aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group)) +
 geom_polygon(aes(fill=cat),color="dim grey", size=.1) +
 scale_fill_manual(values = c("dim grey","#d7191c","#fdae61","#ffffbf","#a6d96a","#1a9641")) +
 # scale_fill_continuous(trans = 'reverse', ) +
 guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=T, title = "%")) +
 labs(title="Projected percentage change of the population, by NUTS2 regions, 2015-2050 (%)",
   subtitle="%",
   caption="(C) EuroGeographics for the administrative boundaries 
   Map produced in R with a help from Eurostat-package <github.com/ropengov/eurostat/>") +
 theme_light() + theme(legend.position=c(.8,.8),   text=element_text(family="opensans")) +
 coord_map(project="orthographic", xlim=c(-12,44), ylim=c(35,70))
```

And same error:

> Error in merge_eurostat_geodata(data = ., geocolumn = "geo",
>   resolution = "20",  :  couldn't find function "merge_eurostat_geodata"

Any idea on how to solve it?